# Insert single successive numbers at the beginning of each line in a text file with Vim

Tags: text-processing, vim

Assume I have a text file containing some strings:

```
string_g
string_r
string_qqwer
string_p
string_f
string_3qw
string_e
string_qw
```

And I need to insert increasing or decreasing numbers before the strings:

```
001 string_g
002 string_r
003 string_qqwer
004 string_p
005 string_f
006 string_3qw
007 string_e
008 string_qw
```

Just to avoid confusion:

I do not want line numbers to be displayed. I know how that works. What I want is an actual number at the beginning of each string within the text.

Is there a way to do this automatically with `vim`?

I can mark the beginning of each string with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> then type <kbd>:</kbd> to enter the execute mode, which will allow me to execute command on the selection via `:'<,'>` but I’m stuck there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use external unix command `nl`.

```
:'<,'>!nl -w 3 -n rz -s' '
```

Comment: Can I start this from an arbitrary number such as say `180`?

Comment: Got it myself: `:'<,'>!nl -v 180 -w 3 -n rz -s' '`
(Sorry for asking and not first reading the manpage!)

Answer (score 2):

With `vim` only (don't use external command):

```
let i=1 | '<,'>g/^/ s//\=printf("%03d ",i) / | let i+=1
```

Change `let i=1` to number you want to start.

Comment: Pretty nice solution too. I just now used it! Because it uses less code I accepted @buff’s answer.